# What preposition should I use after "maintenance"?

Tags: prepositions

While writing an article I ended a paragraph with the sentence

> "The data will require some degree of maintenance **by** the experts"

After rereading, I got stuck on **by** because for some reason it didn't sound right, and my next guess was

> "The data will require some degree of maintenance **from** the experts"

That doesn't sound right either, so now I'm wondering what I'm supposed to write between "maintenance" and "the experts". The meaning I'm trying to convey is simply "The expert will have to maintain the data to some degree."

Comment: Have you considered side-stepping the issue with “The data will require some expert maintenance”?

Comment: @MikeScott in certain contexts, those sentences have different implications. Without knowing the OP’s needs, it’s probably best not to recommend a different sentence unless it’s pretty much the same in meaning.

Comment: @MikeScott In the end I decided to go with "The data will have to be maintained by experts". I asked the question mostly because at times some of the sentences I write "sound off", and in this case I couldn't find a satisfying answer online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked hundreds of examples from the reliable sources including *[YourDictonary](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/maintenance)*. The structure itself is less used. Said that, the word *maintenance of something* is a common practice. So, you need a noun doing *maintenance* of something rather than *maintenance* done by someone. Active/passive style difference there.

Nevertheless, I could find both the usages - *maintenance by* and *maintenance from*. You can use both, IMO. But, you may ask yourself, which goes as a *verb?* *...maintained by/from?* There, you feel that 'by' goes better.

Comment: I think *from* in this case links with *require* rather than *maintain* / *maintenance* - which you've probably not accounted for in your search. "It'll require (maintenance) from the experts" vs. "It'll require (maintenance by the experts)".

Comment: +1, but it’d be good to add an example sentence or two, to clarify things just in case.

Comment: In the end, I wrote "the data will have to be maintained by the experts", similarly to what you suggest in your answer. Thanks for linking that page on YourDictionary, by the way! I didn't know it, I'll be using it the next time I'll have trouble with a sentence.